# Removing overlapping/identical transactions from dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need your help in order to find a method for removing overlapping/identical transactions using Pandas.

Imaging having a list of banktransactions like this, which is df1.

```
+------------------+------------+---------+--------+---------+
| Transaction date | Value date |  Text   | Amount | Balance |
+------------------+------------+---------+--------+---------+
| 26-11-2019       | 26-11-2019 | Apples  |     10 |      90 |
| 26-11-2019       | 26-11-2019 | Bananas |     -5 |      80 |
| 26-11-2019       | 26-11-2019 | Bananas |     -5 |      85 |
| 26-11-2019       | 26-11-2019 | Apples  |    -10 |      90 |
| 26-11-2019       | 26-11-2019 | Apples  |     10 |     100 |
| 25-11-2019       | 25-11-2019 | Pear    |     10 |      90 |
+------------------+------------+---------+--------+---------+
```

In the example then lets further imagine that not all transactions are present per date in df1, so there is another dataframe (df2) which holds the remaining transactions.

```
+------------------+------------+-------------+--------+---------+
| Transaction date | Value date |    Text     | Amount | Balance |
+------------------+------------+-------------+--------+---------+
| 27-11-2019       | 27-11-2019 | Grape fruit |     15 |     125 |
| 26-11-2019       | 26-11-2019 | Pear        |     10 |     110 |
| 26-11-2019       | 26-11-2019 | Apples      |     10 |     100 |
| 26-11-2019       | 26-11-2019 | Apples      |     10 |      90 |
| 26-11-2019       | 26-11-2019 | Bananas     |     -5 |      80 |
| 26-11-2019       | 26-11-2019 | Bananas     |     -5 |      85 |
+------------------+------------+-------------+--------+---------+
```

By comparing df1 and df2 it is clear that the first three rows in df1 are identical to the last three in df2. But at the same time the two dataframes has rows which seems to be duplicates, but the isn't - like the rows with apples like

```
+------------+------------+--------+----+-----+
| 26-11-2019 | 26-11-2019 | Apples | 10 | 100 |
+------------+------------+--------+----+-----+
```

**My question is:** How can I merge these two dataframes into one dataframe and remove the overlapping transactions, but keeping the transactions that seems to be duplicates but isn't?

I have tried to search for a solution to this matter, but it seems that all there is, is either regular merging or removing duplicate transactions.

My own idea is to make some kind of combined unique key from the current, the past and the next transaction. But that raises a whole lot of other issues.

The entire combined dataset in this example is like this

```
+------------------+------------+-------------+--------+---------+
| Transaction date | Value date |    Text     | Amount | Balance |
+------------------+------------+-------------+--------+---------+
| 27-11-2019       | 27-11-2019 | Grape fruit |     15 |     125 |
| 26-11-2019       | 26-11-2019 | Pear        |     10 |     110 |
| 26-11-2019       | 26-11-2019 | Apples      |     10 |     100 |
| 26-11-2019       | 26-11-2019 | Apples      |     10 |      90 |
| 26-11-2019       | 26-11-2019 | Bananas     |     -5 |      80 |
| 26-11-2019       | 26-11-2019 | Bananas     |     -5 |      85 |
| 26-11-2019       | 26-11-2019 | Apples      |    -10 |      90 |
| 26-11-2019       | 26-11-2019 | Apples      |     10 |     100 |
| 25-11-2019       | 25-11-2019 | Pear        |     10 |      90 |
+------------------+------------+-------------+--------+---------+
```

The example data can also be found in [this Excel file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ak4RGlwDcNJ3kZpulac5p6nSd-ToGg?e=AaUgao).

Comment: A normal `pandas.merge()` won’t work?

Comment: Adding to @AlexanderCécile answer, you can later use `.drop_duplicates()` and pass all the columns so you drop any exactly identical row, but not those who have at least one different value in any column.

Comment: Isn’t the row `26-11-2019 26-11-2019 Apples 10 100` actually duplicated, though? Also, can you share your data in a format that is easy for others to use?

Comment: are rows in `df1` or `df2` unique?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile No the ```26-11-2019 26-11-2019 Apples 10 100``` isn't a duplicate. I have just posted the entire dataset as it should be after merging df1 and df2

Comment: @AndyL. No unfortunately not

Comment: As you say the row  `26-11-2019 26-11-2019 Apples 10 100` is not a duplicate even though it shows up both in your first and your second data frame, what is your precise definition of "duplicate" then?

Comment: Yeah, @ctenar beat me to it. Both rows are identical, that's the definition of duplicate. We are clearly missing some information here.

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear about my definition of duplicates - thank you for your patience. The two rows are completly identical by all fields, however hence these two banktransactions are part of the cummulative balance of the bankaccount they can't be deleted. By including both the first three rows in df1 and the last three in df2 will however change the final balance of the account. In order to have the accumulated balance calculated correct (and match the combined dataset example) only one of the two "sets" of three rows can be included in the final df.

Comment: @marj How do you know that? There needs to be some way to differentiate the two, right?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile great question. I know by looking at the account statement. I also know that the bank use some kind of unique reference value per transaction, but that unique reference value isn't exposed in the dataset that is provided.

Comment: @marj You need a way for the machine to be able to tell the difference. How many transactions are you processing? Could marking them manually be viable?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile It is only 100-200 transactions per day, but I will prefer not to do any manual marking. I know it will be hard for the machine to tell the difference between the transactions - and this is where I had the hope that stackoverflow could give a direction for solution.

Comment: @marj It's unlikely that anyone can provide a solution without far more information, unfortunately.